# What should I put in the if statement to get the subclass object element?

Tags: java

```
public static ArrayList <Student> createStudents()
{
    ArrayList<Student> students;
    students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    students.add(new UndergradStudent("Kvin", 15, 'M', 4));
    students.add(new GraduateStudent("Kaley", 24, 'F', "Expert Systems"));
    students.add(new UndergradStudent("Mike", 25, 'M', 2));
    students.add(new GraduateStudent("Bob", 20, 'F', "Extreme Programming"));

    return students;
}
public static void printGradStudents(ArrayList<Student> students)
{
    int count;
    Student student;
    System.out.println("\n\nList of Graduate Students:\n");

    for (count=0; count<students.size(); count++)
    {
        student = students.get(count);
        if (?)
        {
            System.out.println(student);
        }
    }
}
```

## Graduate student is the subclass of Student, What should I put in the if statement if I just want to print out the graduate students' information?##

Comment: The code will be `if (student instanceof Graduate)`,but are you sure you need this? It looks like code smell...

Comment: What you should be doing is implementing a `showInfo()` method overriden by each subclass.

Comment: For all the people who answered: **please** be sure to write **a solution** and not **the fastest way**, note that the *proposed  solution* leads to design problems.

Comment: Please submit your answer as an option, @A--C. Although other answers are technically correct, they promote poor practice.

Comment: He didn't ask about design flaws he asked how to see if the student was a grad student or not. I think the problem with Stack is that people try and fill everyones cup with a fire hose instead of a teaspoon.

Comment: @VisionarySoftwareSolutions @ AMR is right, I gave my 2 cents. Interestingly, all the answers are wrong, instanceof is all lowercase.

Comment: @A--C I would upvoted your solution since it's not a bad practice.

Comment: "How do I hack someone up with a knife?"
"The most efficient way is to start at major veins..."
Perhaps we should begin by asking "why do you want to hack someone up with a knife?" 

StackOverflow is a place where people who don't know what they're doing come to learn. There's nothing "firehose instead of a teaspoon" about showing someone how to do it right.

Comment: @AMR a fisherman ask you for a fish, would you give him the fish or teach him **how to fish**?

Comment: Its about learning the basics first. If you don't know how to do basic things or know about basic functions. Then you should learn that first. Then expand on why it is right or wrong.

Comment: @AMR then you should give both answers and explains the good and bad points of each one instead of providing the `instanceof` as unique solution. We're here to help each other, not to just *give the basics*.

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza I guess a `fisherman` is the one who already knows how to fish! why will he ask you for a fish?? :)

Comment: annnnnnnnnd no one gets the upvote lol #trolledAgain

Comment: Hey guys.  Instead of nitpicking the existing Answers, why don't you write Answers of your own addressing the concerns you have ... **in terms that the OP can understand**.  Bear in mind that it is 99% likely that he is a Java beginner and **will not** understand design concepts / best practice.  Also bear in mind that "best practice" design probably does not apply to a ~100 line application that will be coded, tested, handed in ... and never touched again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (student instanceof GraduateStudent)
```

That should handle it.  instanceof checks to see if it is a member of that class or inherits from that class.  So student will be an instanceOf GraduateStudent and Student

#### Update

As was correctly mentioned in the comments, adding a `showInfo()` class to each instance would be another way of doing this.

Comment: @user2138255 great.  In general, if you find an answer that solves your problem, its suggested that you upvote it and accept it (the up arrow and checkmark to the left of the answers.)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(student instanceof (GraduateStudent))
```

you want to check to see if the class passed in is an instance of either GraduateStudent or underGraduate. It will return a bool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `instanceOf` operator

```
 if(student instanceOf GraduateStudent)
```